# simplexml_load_file can't load an XML file

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to do some very basic parsing of XML data but am failing miserably.

I have a metadata.xml file as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<metadata>
    <page>
        <filename>products.php</filename>
        <title>Best selection of products in Anytown, USA</title>
        <description>We sell quality products</description>
    </page>
    <page>
        <filename>services.com</filename>
        <title>Great services anywhere within Anytown</title>
        <description>Our services are pretty good</description>
    </page>
</metadata>
```

I'm attempting to get a result for a specific XML entry using the code below:

```
<?php
    
$str = simplexml_load_file("metadata.xml") or die("Couldn't load file");

$data = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
// Find the element with specific filename
$nodes = $data->xpath('//metadata/page/filename[.="products.php"]/parent::*');
$result = $nodes[0];
echo "Title: " . $result->title . "\n";
echo "Description: " . $result->description . "\n";

?>
```

This results in an error:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 4: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/html/php_xml_test.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in /var/www/html/php_xml_test.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/php_xml_test.php(10): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('\n\t\n\t\n') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/php_xml_test.php on line 10

If I load the content of the XML file right into the php file everything works fine.

I've read through a bunch of related posts here but can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Add the xml doctype in your xml file

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov Thank you. I added doctype like this but still get the same result:
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE page [
<!ELEMENT page (filename,title,description)>
<!ELEMENT filename (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT description (#PCDATA)>
]>
<metadata>
 <page>
  <filename>products.php</filename>
  <title>Best selection of products in Anytown, USA</title>
  <description>We sell quality products</description>
 </page>
</metadata>`

Comment: You should add only `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

Comment: Unfortunately it till yields the same result with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

Comment: And what happens if you try to load it as string with file_get_contents() and simplexml_load_string() ?

Comment: Changed to: `$xmlfile = file_get_contents('metadata.xml');
 
$str = simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);
`
this resulted in:
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 4: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/html/php_xml_test.php on line 11

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in /var/www/html/php_xml_test.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/php_xml_test.php(11): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('\n\t\n\t\n') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/php_xml_test.php on line 11

Comment: Did you try any online xml parser to verify your xml is actually valid?

Comment: According to https://www.xmlvalidation.com there are not errors. I was able to get it to work using a correction in SimpleXMLElement class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php I adjusted the code like that:

```
<?php

$data = new SimpleXMLElement('metadata.xml', 0, TRUE);
// Find the element with specific filename
$nodes = $data->xpath('//metadata/page/filename[.="services.php"]/parent::*');
$result = $nodes[0];
echo "Title: " . $result->title . "\n";
echo "Description: " . $result->description . "\n";

?>
```